# How can I configure uglifyjs from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, uglifyjs, package.json

Currently, when developing Wordpress themes I use a simple batch file to uglify my js. 
An example batch file `makebundle.bat`

```
call uglifyjs^
  src/file1.js^
  src/file2.js^
  -cmo bundle.min.js
```

I then use `watch` to build it like this

```
watch makebundle src
```

All very simple. Now, I'd like to make this a less Windows-specific process. For the
[reasons outlined here](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/why-we-should-stop-using-grunt/)
I don't want to use Grunt / Gulp, and was thinking of trying to 
[use npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).
The only trouble is, **I can't find out how to configure uglifyjs 
from within `package.json`**

**edit**

Here's an example of something I'd like to work in `package.json`:

```
{
  "uglifyConfig": [
    {
      "outfile": "bundle.min.js,
      "files": [
        "src/file1.js",
        "src/file2.js"
      ]
      "config": {
        "mangle": true,
        "compress": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If your build script is a node script, you can use Uglify's JavaScript API instead of the command-line API.  You can easily `require()` your package.json, read configuration from it, and pass those values to Uglify.

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ugly": "node do-uglify.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

do-uglify.js:

```
var uglify = require('uglify');
var package = require('./package.json');
var uglifyConfig = package.uglifyConfig;
// Call the UglifyJS Javascript API, passing config from uglifyConfig
```

Comment: Thanks, I may give this one a try, though writing my own build build script starts to eat away at the whole point of avoiding Grunt etc. It does have the benefit of being more platform-independent than my current method, though.

Comment: Yeah, but that's why so many of us *do* use Grunt.  Despite feeling heavy and verbose, it overcomes the limitations of package.json, gives us cross-platform file globbing, etc.  In a follow-up to the blog post you linked, the author admits Unix-style globbing doesn't work on Windows, and yet his npm scripts use it extensively.http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Comment: I do link to that post as well in my question, and I take your point. I do find it strange though that no-one has used uglify directly with package.json though, in the way that I'm after.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I didn't see that you had linked both posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any scripts you want in the "scripts" section of `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ugly": "uglify",
    "prepublish" : "uglify"
  },
...
```

You can give it any arbitrary name and run it with `npm run ugly` or use one of the [predefined hooks](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) such as `prepublish`

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to include the configuration for it in package.json too - e.g. something like an array of js files to concat / minify.

Comment: Why not specify the files by path `uglify lib/*` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you mean specifying a glob in the `scripts` object, then I'd like to order the files explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the exact same thing today and this is the most relevant and number one hit on google.

The example by Gangstead is correct but incomplete, when somebody asks this type of question they likely need a complete answer, and possibly even some context and explanation.

Here is the full solution:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "abridge-bundle",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Abridge - bundle and minify js",
  "author": "Jake G <106644+Jieiku@users.noreply.github.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Jieiku/abridge",
  "scripts": {
    "uglify": "uglifyjs public/search_index.en.js public/elasticlunr.min.js public/search.js -c -m -o static/search_bundle.min.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "^3.15.4"
  }
}
```

The above package.json file can be used to generate minified js file by typing npm run uglify.

In my case I deploy to netlify, so here is the netlify.toml as well:

```
[build]
publish = "public"
command = "zola build && npm run uglify"

[build.environment]
ZOLA_VERSION = "0.16.0"

[context.deploy-preview]
command = "zola build --base-url $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL && npm run uglify"

[[headers]]
  for = "/*"
  [headers.values]
    X-Frame-Options = "DENY"
    X-Content-Type-Options = "nosniff"
    X-XSS-Protection = "1; mode=block"
    Referrer-Policy = "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    Strict-Transport-Security = "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
    Content-Security-Policy = "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: cdn.cloudflare.com; frame-src 'self' www.youtube-nocookie.com player.vimeo.com; media-src 'self' data: cdn.cloudflare.com www.youtube-nocookie.com player.vimeo.com; font-src 'self' cdn.cloudflare.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.cloudflare.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com;"
```

These are currently viewable at my repository as well (zola static site generator theme): https://github.com/Jieiku/abridge